# Downloading bar in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to create a downloading Bar means it increases as Downloading percentage increases in the background of a list row. I don't know How to implement this in Android. Please suggest me for right result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try searching for LINQ tutorials? There are *loads* out there...

Comment: I dont understand how this question is linked to LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out for Linq Tutorials... FROM Source:[What are some good LINQ resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47740/what-are-some-good-linq-resources/58272)

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

[www.linqtutorial.net](http://www.linqtutorial.net)

FROM [ScottGu's blog]

- [Part 1: Introduction to LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)
- [Part 2: Defining our Data Model Classes](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/29/linq-to-sql-part-2-defining-our-data-model-classes.aspx)
- [Part 3: Querying our Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/29/linq-to-sql-part-3-querying-our-database.aspx)
- [Part 4: Updating our Database](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/11/linq-to-sql-part-4-updating-our-database.aspx)
- [Part 5: Binding UI using the ASP:LinqDataSource Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/16/linq-to-sql-part-5-binding-ui-using-the-asp-linqdatasource-control.aspx)
- [Part 6: Retrieving Data Using Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)
- [Part 7: Updating our Database using Stored Procedures](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx)
- [Part 8: Executing Custom SQL Expressions](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/27/linq-to-sql-part-8-executing-custom-sql-expressions.aspx)
- [Part 9: Using a Custom LINQ Expression with the `<asp:LinqDatasource>` control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/09/07/linq-to-sql-part-9-using-a-custom-linq-expression-with-the-lt-asp-linqdatasource-gt-control.aspx)

Comment: why did you change you question?

Comment: because there are negative responses towards that

Comment: So what!!! If you find answer of your question then it's OK, PLEASE, Revert your question and accept answer if it helps you...

Comment: Everybody can see your edited question... and it's not good to change question like this....

Comment: Please, edited your question to original one.... if anybody read the question, they get proper answer also.... Thanks.